# Google Maps API Error

Tags: android, dictionary

I am trying to develop one app for Google map v2. i followed the all the instructions. i generate API_KEY and placed it into android manifest file also. But i get the error when i run app in emulator as well as android device also. my log cat fallow the error like

```
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5089000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.I(Unknown Source)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.H(Unknown Source)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.jz(Unknown Source)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
09-22 17:55:53.720: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  ... 24 more
```

here is my android manifest file

```
 <permission
    android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCQrpK7QEIW86IaH6pEKbeln-sJ6i1amGU" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

i gave valid API_KEY but error was like that what happened.please give me solution for this problem...

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the google play services version to your manifest

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

You can read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#install_the_android_sdk

Comment: Thank you zerd1984 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 5089000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the  element:     `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Try to add that in manifest

```
</activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCQrpK7QEIW86IaH6pEKbeln-sJ6i1amGU" />

   <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"     
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

</application>
```